# How to give azure data lake storage gen2 URL value from AKV secret name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service, akv2k8s

I have azure account, and want to create azure data lake storage gen2 URL value from AKV secret name value,

I created AKV and created secret name and in the value I gave my storage URL like:

```
https://storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

I want to give this value into here dynamically from AKV secret value:

[image]

and I dont know how to do that but I am guessing may be I should use json here and give credentials I am not sure.

this json format

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to give this value into here dynamically from AKV secret value:

To achieve this, first you need to get the AKV secret value in ADF. Use **web activity** to do that. Follow the steps in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities) to get the secret value in web activity output.

It will directly, show the secret value in the web activity output.

[image]

To prevent the secret value to be shown in the output of web activity, Check Secure output option in the web activity.

[image]

Now, it will secure the output like below.

[image]

You need to pass this secret value from this activity output to the linked service.

Go to linked service and click on **edit**. Use the below expression in the **URL** dynamic content like below.

```
@{activity('Web1').output.value}
```

Ignore the warning here.

[image]

Save these edits. Here, I have given the path of my data file and use a lookup dataset after the web activity to check the result. You can see it gave me the expected results.

[image]

Comment: but I am not able to put this value in the linked service @{activity('Web1').output.value}

Comment: You need to type that as it is in that URL dynamic expression. Ignore the warning message because it will work in debug state.